# How to create and add new variable to dataframe to print to excel using Pandas and Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I am trying to create a new variable "spg", or shots per game using Pandas on Python. This new variable is simply s/gp or shots/games played. I would like to add this new variable to my current dataframe so I can print it to excel.

I would like my final columns to look like this:
columns = ("name", "team", "gp", "g", "s", "spg")

```
# import modules

from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring

import pandas as pd

# connect to url

url = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2020_skaters.html"

# remove HTML comment markup

content = str(urlopen(url).read())

comment = content.replace("-->", "").replace("<!--", "")
tree = fromstring(comment)

# setting up excel columns

columns = ("name", "team", "gp", "g", "s")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# parsing data while using loop

for idx, row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//table[@id="stats"]/tbody/tr[not(@class="thead")]')):
    name = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]')[0].text_content()
    team = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="team_id"]')[0].text_content()
    gp = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="games_played"]')[0].text_content()
    goals = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="goals"]')[0].text_content()
    s = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="shots"]')[0].text_content()


    # create pandas dataframe to export data to excel.

    df.loc[idx] = (name, team, gp, goals, s) # I would like to add "spg"
    print(df)


# write data to excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('NHL skater20.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Any recommendations on the best way to do this? I greatly appreciate any help or feedback I can get. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: after the loop, add this line:

```
df['spg'] = df['s'] / df['gp']
```

**UPD:** (tested and working)

```
# import modules

from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring

import pandas as pd

# connect to url

url = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2020_skaters.html"

# remove HTML comment markup

content = str(urlopen(url).read())

comment = content.replace("-->", "").replace("<!--", "")
tree = fromstring(comment)

# setting up excel columns

columns = ("name", "team", "gp", "g", "s")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# parsing data while using loop

for idx, row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//table[@id="stats"]/tbody/tr[not(@class="thead")]')):
    name = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]')[0].text_content()
    team = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="team_id"]')[0].text_content()
    gp = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="games_played"]')[0].text_content()
    goals = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="goals"]')[0].text_content()
    s = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="shots"]')[0].text_content()


    # create pandas dataframe to export data to excel.
    # this is fine for a small dataset, however
    # for a bigger one writing a generator is much more efficient
    df.loc[idx] = (name, team, gp, goals, s) # I would like to add "spg"
    # print(df)  # commented out as unnecessary

# at this point these columns are .text_content(), converting to numbers
df = df.astype({'gp': int, 'g': int, 's': int})
# main part: adding a new column
df['spg'] = df['s'] / df['gp']

# write data to excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('NHL skater20.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Marat. Can you please show me in the code? I have tried adding the code but I am getting a NameError: name 'spg' is not defined. I am still new so any advice would be very helpful. =)

Comment: @AbleArcher added full code. The only change is two lines before creating `writer`

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for! Thank you @Marat for sharing some knowledge! Much appreciated good sir! =)

Answer (score 1):

To send it to excel you can use either of these:

```
DataFrame.to_excel('filename.xlsx')
DataFrame.to_csv('filename.csv')
```